# JButton isn't being called after pressing other JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

If enter in a string in the JTextBox, than press the "enter button", it returns the correct data in the JTextField, if I change the string, and repress enter the correct data is returned too. If I press the "enter button" and than press the "add" button (which adds the data to the JList, and re-calls the Gui method in order to update the JList), if I try entering in another string into the JTextField, nothing happens when I press the enter button.
I'm not seeing why this is, if anyone sees something I don't, it'd be cool if you could tell me.

```
package movieinfo;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import com.json.parsers.JSONParser;
import com.json.parsers.JsonParserFactory;

public class Swinggui {
    private static JButton enter;
    private static JTextField movietext;
    private static JTextArea movieinfo;
    private static JList listofmovies;// converts moviestowatch into gui
                                        // element.
    private static File textfilemovie; // file which movies marked for watching
                                        // are saved
    private static java.util.List<String> moviestowatch; // arraylist which is
                                                            // populated by
                                                            // textfilemovie
                                                            // than printed to
                                                            // GUI element
    private static JsonParserFactory factory;
    private static JSONParser parser;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static Map jsonData;
    private static ListSelectionListener setSearch;
    private static JButton add;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        yourMovies();
        gui();
        jsonAndButtons();

    }

    public static void gui() {
        JFrame maingui = new JFrame("Gui");
        maingui.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        enter = new JButton("Get Info");
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        maingui.add(enter, c);
        add = new JButton("add");
        c.gridx = 5;
        c.gridy = 6;
        maingui.add(add, c);
        movieinfo = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        movieinfo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2,
                Color.red));
        movietext = new JTextField(18);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        maingui.add(movietext, c);
        final JScrollPane scrolll = new JScrollPane(movieinfo);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        maingui.add(scrolll, c);
        final JLabel titlee = new JLabel("Enter movie name below!");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        maingui.add(titlee, c);
        final JLabel info = new JLabel("Info");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        maingui.add(titlee, c);
        final JLabel watchlist = new JLabel("Watchlist");
        c.gridx = 5;
        c.gridy = 1;
        maingui.add(watchlist, c);
        maingui.setResizable(false);
        maingui.setVisible(true);
        listofmovies = new JList(moviestowatch.toArray());
        c.gridx = 4;
        c.gridy = 3;
        maingui.add(new JScrollPane(listofmovies), c);
        movieinfo.setLineWrap(true);
        movieinfo.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        movieinfo.setEditable(false);
        scrolll.getPreferredSize();
        listofmovies.addListSelectionListener(setSearch);
        maingui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        maingui.pack();

    }

    public static void jsonAndButtons() {
        enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.out.println(apicall.getMovieInfo(movietext.getText().replaceAll(" ", "%20")));
                factory = JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
                parser = factory.newJsonParser();
                jsonData = parser.parseJson(apicall.getMovieInfo(movietext
                        .getText().replaceAll(" ", "%20")));
                String Title = (String) jsonData.get("Title");
                String Year = (String) jsonData.get("Year");
                String Plot = (String) jsonData.get("Plot");
                movieinfo.setText("Title: " + Title + "\nYear: " + Year
                        + "\nPlot: " + Plot);

            }

        });
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    FileUtils.writeStringToFile( new File(
                            org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.getUserDirectory()
                            + "/yourmovies.txt"), "\n" + movietext.getText(), true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  
                try {
                    moviestowatch = FileUtils.readLines(textfilemovie);
                    jsonAndButtons();
                    gui();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }); 

    }

    public static void yourMovies() throws IOException {
        textfilemovie = new File(
                org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.getUserDirectory()
                        + "/yourmovies.txt");
        textfilemovie.createNewFile();
        moviestowatch = FileUtils.readLines(textfilemovie);
        setSearch = new ListSelectionListener() {

            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
                factory = JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
                parser = factory.newJsonParser();
                jsonData = parser.parseJson(apicall.getMovieInfo(((String) listofmovies
                        .getSelectedValue()).replaceAll(" ", "%20")));
                String Title = (String) jsonData.get("Title");
                String Year = (String) jsonData.get("Year");
                String Plot = (String) jsonData.get("Plot");
                movieinfo.setText("Title: " + Title + "\nYear: " + Year
                        + "\nPlot: " + Plot);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: The basic design of you GUI is wrong. You should NOT be using static methods and variables. I suggest you look at the Swing tutorial for working exmaples to give you a better idea how to structure your code.

Comment: Well, If I remove the static modifiers, I am told I am accessings non-static fields via means which are static. I don't really see how my ways of accessing are static, and quite honestly, looking at the swing tutorials aren't helping me too much understand that.

Comment: There is no time like the present to learn the proper way to code. The idea is to start with a working example from the tutorial and then make changes for your particular requirement. Maybe start with the `LabelDemo` from the section on `How to Use Labels`. It shows you hove to properly build the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread. Yes the code does use a couple of static methods but this is only to create the frame, not the heart of your application which would be the JPanel. So modify the example to add your components to the panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your actionListener for the "add" button, you are again calling the jsonAndButtons() and gui() methods, which is recreating the buttons. That may be causing the weird behavior.

Comment: Let me look into a better way of refreshing the items in the JList.